# Can carelessness and lack of consistency in the hiring process be considered a form of discrimination?

Tags: employment

I applied for a position as an independent contractor with a well-known tutoring company. Using their platform would have been an excellent opportunity for me.

Unfortunately, my application was denied without any reasonable explanation or additional details on their part. I'm a highly qualified ACT tutor who scored in the 99th percentile in every subject area on the exam. I have experience with another nationally recognized tutoring company and received excellent reviews on their platform. I submitted a thorough and engaging profile and know I could have helped dozens of students succeed on this life-changing test.

However, I can provide countless examples of approved pages on their site with typos, blatant grammatical errors, and lack of detail. The grammatical errors are particularly disturbing considering these tutors are supposed to be experts in the conventions of standard English. I can find no reasonable explanation as to why my profile was denied and these were approved other than negligence on the part of their content review team. I believe I'm being discriminated against and arbitrarily being denied an opportunity to make a living.

Comment: In fact I could think of some ways of carelessness as a defense against claims of discrimination. If it was discovered that the applicants were approved or not only on the basis of, say, throwing dices, the random nature of the process could make any charges of discrimination patently invalid. I am not a lawyer, by the way.

Comment: And in any case discrimination is not illegal in general, only when it is done on the ground of some protected characteristic (sex, race...). For example chosing the candidate with the best resumé is discrimination against the candidates with poor resumés, but it is of course perfectly legal. Even discriminating against the best candidates would be legal.

Comment: You make several good points. However, it's unfortunate this company is operating in this manner and essentially playing with people's ability to earn a living.

Comment: I don't see anything in your question to suggest discrimination. They may have hired less qualified people for any number of reasons (random chance, lack of attention, other qualities not evident on their site). As pointed out, there are relatively few "protected characteristics" which cannot be used legally in a hiring decision, but you haven't mentioned any of them here. On the contrary, you feel you are being denied "arbitrarily", which means there isn't *any* reason for the rejection, much less an illegal one.

Comment: Should be pointed out that their web page wasn't likely made by tutors but software developers who, I can attest, are not always the best at correct grammar (and front end code is not formatted in a way that is conducive to reading the statements that will be displayed on a page).   Just because they hired programmers with poor command of English Language Grammar doesn't mean they hire poor tutors of English Language Grammar.  It just means the employees don't use the primary services.

Comment: They hired tutors with poor grammar that are supposed to prepare students for the ACT English exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carelessness is not a form of discrimination: it approaches being a form of non-discrimination. Hiring decisions are usually not made at random, instead employers discriminate between viable and non-viable candidates based on "qualifications", which are job specific. In a completely non-discriminatory system, candidates would be selected at random and would not be distinguished in terms of test scores, licenses, work experience, or anything else. A system of hiring where decisions sometimes follow a set of criteria and sometimes don't (i.e. they are careless in applying test scores) approaches a completely non-discriminatory system.

Certain kinds of criteria constitute *illegal* discrimination, depending on jurisdiction and the nature of the job. For example, religion, race, race, sex, veteran status, postal code, national origin, marital status might be illegal bases for making a hiring decision. If you have evidence that the real reason for your not being hired is an illegal factor such as race (since this is a US company, it would be), you could file a complaint. Postal code is not a protected characteristic in the US, nor is age.

Comment: I now see it can't be defined as discrimination. However, do I have any recourse if I can show it was random and arbitrary? I was really hurt by their decision and can show that less qualified candidates were accepted.

Comment: @user27343 They have no business relation or any other relationship with you. They have no responsibility whatsover towards you to make decisions that don't hurt you. Also: How have you been hurt? You had no job, and you still have no job, so nothing has changed. If they had promised you a job and you quit your old one, then you would have been hurt, and they had a relationship with you (by promising you a job), which together _might_ make them responsible for damages. But they didn't promise you anything.